# issue in dm2seasonal function in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, zoo

I am trying to calculate the cumulative precipitation by season in R using the function `dm2seasonal`.
As an example, this is the `str` of the first element in my zoo list of stations with daily precipitation :

(I have not include for example the `dput(listDF_zoo[[1]])` because limit of characters)

```
> str(listDF_zoo[[1]])
‘zoo’ series from 1915-11-01 to 1945-11-01
  Data: num [1:9382] 0 0 0 0 0 18.5 9.4 0 0 10.4 ...
  Index:  Date[1:9382], format: "1915-11-01" "1915-11-02" "1915-11-03" "1915-11-04" "1915-11-05" "1915-11-06" "1915-11-07" ...
```

I am using the following code:

```
#Cumulative precipitation in spring (March 1 to May 31)
SpringCumMean <- lapply(listDF_zoo,function(x){dm2seasonal(x, season ="MAM", FUN=sum)})
```

but I got the following error:

```
> SpringCumMean <- lapply(listDF_zoo,function(x){dm2seasonal(x, season ="MAM", FUN=sum)})
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate In addition: Warning message:
In extract.zoo(x = x, trgt = season) :
  There were no elements of 'x' within 'trgt'
```

and I do not understand why is saying that the element does not have rows...

Any solution?

Comment: Please show a non-lapply,, single call of `dm2seasonal` that works. Method appears to depend on `aggregate` which can return `no rows to aggregate` due to missing observations.

Comment: I know I got the error in element 46 of the list. Is it possible to skip the error in the loop to avoid stop the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since data appears to be data-specific on one element in list, consider `tryCatch` where you conditionally return `NULL` (or any other object or value) on error instances.

```r
SpringCumMean <- lapply(listDF_zoo,function(x) {
                         tryCatch({
                              dm2seasonal(x, season ="MAM", FUN=sum)
                         }, error = function(e) NULL)
                 })
```

And should you need to filter out the `NULL` elements, consider `Filter`. But doing so, `SpringCumMean` will no longer maintain equal length to `listDF_zoo`.

```
SpringCumMean <- Filter(length, SpringCumMean)
```